# Algorithm to iteratively discover points on an arc described by three points

Tags: algorithm, interpolation

I am writing a graphics application that needs to calculate and display a list of points along a <strike>curve</strike> arc which is described by three points.

Lets say we have points (1,1), (2,4) and (5,2).  I need an algorithm that can give me the values of y for each x from 1 to 5 that fall on the interpolated arc.

I'm sure this is a simple task for you math whizes out there, but for me it's a bit beyond my mathematical payscale.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of curve are you generating? Bezìer, Spline, Hermite, B-Spline? What have you tried so far? What are you stuck at?

Comment: I need the curve to be the arc that intersects all three points.  It's been 30 years since I had geometry and I'm struggling just coming up with the terms I need to ask the question. :)

Comment: The problem is that there are an infinite number of curves that can go through 3 points. You need to settle on the shape of the curve first.

Comment: Isn't an arc specifically the only curve between the three points are equidistant from a central point?

Comment: Your question did not say equidistant from a central point.

Comment: I edited the question to say arc instead of curve.  Am I wrong to assume that is descriptive enough?

Comment: The equattion of a circle is (x-a)(x-a) + (y-b)*(y-b) = r*r  problem is that 4 unknows.  You know the line the center has to be on so you have to use that.

Comment: @Blam - How do I determine R for the three points?

Comment: http://www.mathopenref.com/const3pointcircle.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is how to compute the center `C = (c1, c2)` and radius `r` of a circumference given by three points `P = (p1, p2)`, `Q = (q1, q2)` and `S = (s1, s2).`

The idea is very simple. It consists in realizing that, by definition, the center has the same distance to all three points `P`, `Q` and `S.`

[image]

Now, the set of all points that are equidistant from `P`and `Q` is the perpendicular to the segment `PQ` incident at the mid point `(P+Q)/2`. Similarly, the set of all points equidistant from `Q` and `S` is the perpendicular to `QS` passing thru `(Q+S)/2.` So, the center `C` must be the intersection of these two lines.

Let's compute the parametric equations of these two straight lines.

For this we will need two additional functions that I will call `dist(A,B)` which computes the distance between points `A` and `B` and `perp(A,B)` that normalizes the vector `B-A` dividing it by its length (or norm) and answers the perpendicular vector to this normalized vector (keep in mind that a perpendicular to `(a,b)` is `(-b,a)` because their inner product is `0`)

```
dist((a1,a2),(b1,b2))
    Return sqrt(square(b1-a1) + square(b2-a2))

perp((a1,a2),(b1,b2))
    dist := dist((a1,a2),(b1,b2)).
    a := (b1-a1)/dist.
    b := (b2-a2)/dist.
    Return (-b,a).
```

We can now write the parametric expressions of our two lines

```
(P+Q)/2 + perp(P,Q)*t
(Q+S)/2 + perp(Q,S)*u
```

Note that both parameters are different, hence the introduction of two variables `t` and `u`.

Equating these parametric expressions:

```
(P+Q)/2 + perp(P,Q)*t = (Q+S)/2 + perp(Q,S)*u
```

which consists of two linear equations, one for each coordinate, and two unknowns `t` and `u` (see below). The solution of this 2x2 system gives the values of the parameters `t` and `u` that injected into the parametric expressions give the center `C` of the circumference.

Once `C` is known, the radius `r` can be calculated as `r := dist(P,C).`

---

**Linear equations**

```
(P+Q)/2 + perp(P,Q)*t = (Q+S)/2 + perp(Q,S)*u
```

*First linear equation* (coordinate x)

```
(p1+q1)/2 + (p2-q2)/dist(P,Q)*t = (q1+s1)/2 + (q2-s2)/dist(Q,S)*u
```

*Second linear equation* (coordinate y)

```
(p2+q2)/2 + (q1-p1)/dist(P,Q)*t = (q2+s2)/2 + (s1-q1)/dist(Q,S)*u
```

*Linear System* (2x2)

```
(p2-q2)/dist(P,Q)*t + (s2-q2)/dist(Q,S)*u = (s1-p1)/2
(q1-p1)/dist(P,Q)*t + (q1-s1)/dist(Q,S)*u = (s2-p2)/2
```